# Why does my code error when the tutorial I used does not have an error at all?

Tags: c++, gml

I've followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qf7Ol1ipssQ) tutorial character by character but for some reason I get the following error:

" 1>c:\users\fish's ocean\source\repos\dll1\dll1\dll1.cpp(47): error C2664: 'bool (ds_map,char *,double)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [5]' to 'char *' "

also at lines 48 and 49.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ6AH.png) is what my Visual Studio looks like on those lines, but for some reason the tutorial does not have the error and I can't figure out the difference (He goes over these lines somewhere around 17 minute mark)

```
// Dll1.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

#define gmx extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

using ds_map = int;
using thread = std::thread;
using milliseconds = std::chrono::milliseconds;

const int EVENT_OTHER_SOCIAL = 70;

void(*gml_event_perform_async)(ds_map map, int event_type) = nullptr;
int(*gml_ds_map_create)(int n, ...) = nullptr;
bool(*gml_ds_map_add_double)(ds_map map, char* key, double value);
bool(*gml_ds_map_add_string)(ds_map map, char* key, char* value);

std::mutex thread_key;

std::vector<thread*> threads;
std::vector<uint32_t> open_slots;

gmx double RegisterCallbacks(char * arg1, char* arg2, char* arg3, char* arg4) {
gml_event_perform_async = (void(*)(ds_map, int))arg1;
gml_ds_map_create = (int(*)(int, ...))arg2;
gml_ds_map_add_double = (bool(*)(ds_map, char*, double))arg3;
gml_ds_map_add_string = (bool(*)(ds_map, char*, char*))arg4;
return 0;
}

ds_map ds_map_create() {
return gml_ds_map_create(0);
}

void return_double(double time, double type, double value, int handle) {
long t = (long)time;
std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(t));

thread_key.lock();

ds_map map = ds_map_create();
gml_ds_map_add_double(map, "type", type);
gml_ds_map_add_double(map, "value", value);
gml_ds_map_add_double(map, "handle", handle);
gml_event_perform_async(map, EVENT_OTHER_SOCIAL);

thread_key.lock();
}

gmx double thread_create(double time, double type, double value) {
int index;

thread_key.lock();

if (open_slots.empty()) {
    index = threads.size();
    threads.push_back(new thread(return_double, time, type, value, index));
}
else {
    index = open_slots.back();
    open_slots.pop_back();
    threads[index] = new thread(return_double, time, type, value, index);
}

thread_key.unlock();
return index;
}

gmx double thread_kill(double index) {
thread_key.lock();

if (threads.size() > index && threads[index] != NULL) {
    if (threads[index]->joinable()) {
        threads[index]->detach();
    }
    delete threads[index];
    threads[index] = NULL;
    open_slots.push_back(index);
}
thread_key.unlock();
return 1;
}

gmx double thread_free(double index) {
thread_key.lock();

if (threads.size() > index && threads[index] != NULL) {
    if (threads[index]->joinable()) {
        threads[index]->join();
    }
    delete threads[index];
    threads[index] = NULL;
    open_slots.push_back(index);
}
thread_key.unlock();
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: I would say the declarations of `gml_ds_map_add_double` and `..._add_string` need to have a `const char*` as the second argument. But I don't know the library, so I don't know if this is correct.

Comment: That causes "1>c:\users\fish's ocean\source\repos\dll1\dll1\dll1.cpp(31): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'bool (__cdecl *)(ds_map,char *,double)' to 'bool (__cdecl *)(ds_map,const char *,double)'" (and a similar error on line 32)

Comment: This is an issue of const correctness. You can't remove const: i.e. you can't convert `const char *` to `char *` because then you could change it, thus violating const.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that your tutorial is ancient.  Way back a long time ago, some compilers would allow passing a character string - `"type"` to a parameter that wanted a `char *`, or assigning these values to a `char *` variable.  (Character strings were not treated as constants.)

This was changed so that character strings are constant (and read only).  This means that most (if not all) of your `char *` parameters in functions, function pointers, and prototypes need to be changed to `const char *` in order to work with the character strings you're using.  However, this would mean the functions being used as callbacks would also need to have their signatures changed.

And `RegisterCallbacks` should take the proper function prototypes for all the parameters, and not accept them as `char *` values.  These days, the casts required to pull that off can easily lead to Undefined Behavior.